# Is it a recommended in the Quran to marry a beautiful woman?

Tags: practical-islam, nikah

Assalamu Alaikum,

My family is looking for proposals and the men used to get invited to home for seeing the women, only after liking the women, the marriage is forwarded. if the guy didn't like the girl, there won't be any further discussion and proposal would be cancelled fore after.
 Most guys reject me because I'm not beautiful.
 Does Islam has anything to do with this guys??
 Is it something bad to judge someone from color or external beauty in islam??

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it a recommended in the Quran to marry a beautiful woman?**

**No.** The Quran specifically does not say anything about what kind of girl a man should marry. However, there are hadiths that encourage Muslims to marry religious women.

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him)
>   that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:
>   “Women may be married for four things: their wealth, their lineage,
>   their beauty and their religious commitment. Choose the one who is
>   religiously-committed, may your hands be rubbed with dust (i.e., may
>   you prosper).” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (4802) and Muslim (1466).

Al-Nawawi said in Sharh Muslim (10/52):

> "The correct view concerning the meaning of this hadeeth is that the
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) was speaking of
>   what people usually do, which is that they look for these four
>   characteristics, the last of which in their view is religious
>   commitment, but you who are rightly guided should choose the one who
>   is religiously committed."

---

> **Does Islam has anything to do with these guys?**

Islam encourages Muslims to marry religious women but it's not obligatory. If a man wishes to marry a beautiful girl, then it's his personal choice.

> **Is it something bad to judge someone from color or external beauty in
>   islam?**

Of course it is bad. The prophet (peace be upon him) said:

> **Behold! Verily, there is no good in red skin or black skin, but rather only by virtue of righteousness.**